# 'An item with the same key has already been added'

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I am trying to send some data to the database via this form. I keep getting the error about an item with the same key has already been added.

I have been trying to debug this error for quite some time now. I did have several elements that were getting assigned the same name by their @Html helpers, but I thought I cleared them up.

```
<div id="addNewUser" class="newUser" style="border: solid black 2px">
    <form name="newUser" method="post" action="@Url.Action("Submit", "Roles")">
        <h4>Add New User</h4>
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
            <div id="ddlNewUserHealthPlan" class="form-group">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NewUserHealthPlans, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.GetHealthPlans(Model.HEALTHPLAN), "Select a Healthplan", new { @class = "form-group", @id = "ddlNewUserHealthPlanSelect" })
            </div>
            <div id="ddlNewUserRoles" class="form-group">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Roles, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.GetUserRoles(Model.USERROLE), "Select a Role", new { @class = "form-group", @id = "ddlNewUserRoleSelect" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("User Id: ")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User_Id, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div id="ddlNewUserPrimaryHP" class="form-group">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NewUserPrimaryHealthPlan, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.GetHealthPlans(Model.HEALTHPLAN), "Select a Primary Healthplan", new { @class = "form-group", @id = "newUserPrimaryHP" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <br />
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content:center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add new User</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

**Saving the user**

```
public void SaveUser(SearchRolesViewModel objSearchRolesViewModel, string userID)
        {
            USERACCOUNT objUserAccount = new USERACCOUNT
            {
                HPID = Convert.ToInt32(objSearchRolesViewModel.NewUserHealthPlans),
                DOMAIN = "Aeth",
                NTUSERID = objSearchRolesViewModel.User_Id,
                ROLEID = Convert.ToInt32(objSearchRolesViewModel.UserRole),
                FIRSTNAME = "Matthew",
                LASTNAME = "Wright",
                EMAIL = "MW@test.com",
                ACTIVE = Convert.ToBoolean(objSearchRolesViewModel.ActiveStatus),
                DEFAULTPLANID = Convert.ToInt32(objSearchRolesViewModel.NewUserPrimaryHealthPlan),
                CREATEID = userID,
                CREATEDATE = DateTime.Now,
                UPDATEID = userID,
                UPDATEDATE = DateTime.Now
            };
            _context.USERACCOUNTs.Add(objUserAccount);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

**Stack Trace**

```
[ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) +52
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) +13007142
   System.Collections.Generic.CollectionExtensions.ToDictionaryFast(TValue[] array, Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext.get_PropertyMetadata() +149
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) +176
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperties(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +101
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model) +55
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +1209
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +333
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +105
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +640
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +346
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +494
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_1(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +403
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +427
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +103
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159
```

Thank you!

Comment: The same key means you are trying to save a new record with PrimaryKey that already exists in the database. Are you using EntityFramework? or how are you saving to the database? It would be helpful to show us your database definition.

Comment: Post the exact error message, and how/when it happens. If possible with a stack-trace.  It is now unclear if you have an MVC data-binding issue or a database problem.

Comment: Also post your server side code where you are attempting to save

Comment: What do you have defined as your primary key on your USERACCOUNT table?

Comment: USERID is the PK.

Comment: Is USERID represenative of a int, Guid, or like a physical user id like mwright?

Comment: The USERID = int

Comment: It's now clear that you have a data-binding issue, forget about the PK and EF.

Comment: So likely cause is that you don't have it set as an auto Incrementing ID in your database. Got to the table > expand columns > right click properties. Identity should be set to true and Identity Increment should be set to 1. This means as you feed records in it will auto create the ID as the last ID plus 1, otherwise you have to handle setting the ID value explicitly yourself in code which you are nto doing. The error you are recieving is saying that your code is trying to save a record with a primary key that already exists, which is indicative of auto incremnt off.

Comment: That was one of my attempts to fix...the Table has Identity set to 'True' and Identity Increment set at '1'.

Comment: And after you made that change you went and refreshed your EF model as well? (Honestly it is easier sometimes to remove the table and re-add it)

Comment: Fiddler should be able to provide you with enough information to quickly identify the data causing the model binding issue.

Comment: It seems that there is a problem in binding for UserId. Did you check out is UserId is binding right?

Comment: @SamAxe I'm brand new to using Fiddler. The developer I had helping me yesterday said that based on what he saw in Fiddler it looked ok. Any advice on where to look to check for the issue?

Comment: @MatthewWright: nope.  I don't have telepathic abilities.  Can't see what you and/or your other developer saw yesterday.  I got nuffin.

Comment: "@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User_Id..."  Is this the same as the primary key? If so, that is a problem.  You are asking the user to input a value for a primary key, but these should be generated when the record is created.